# How to loop through list evalute first char of each item of list

Tags: python, list

**Problem:**
 How do I loop through a list, look at the first char in each list item. If the first char `= "0"` then remove the "0" then look at next item in list for same evaluation. else: leave it as is.

**Code thus far:**

```
gList = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "094G.005", "194G.015"]

for x in gList:
    lGrid[i].lstrip("0")
    print gList
else:
    pass
```

**Desired Output:**

```
gList = ["94G.016", "94G.019", "94G.005", "194G.015"]
```

**Research:**

I can use `gList.lstrip("0")` to remove the zero from the first item in the list but don't know how to get it to move to the next entry and repeat the process.

Alternatively:
I know I can use `gList[0][0]` to select the first list/char item but again need way for it to loop through the list.

**EDIT: Using a generator:**

**Code thus far:**

```
def rem0(data):
    (x.lstrip('0') for x in lGrid)
    yield x

for i in rem0(lGrid):
    print i
```

**Desired Output:**

```
gList = ["94G.016", "94G.019", "94G.005", "194G.015"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> gList = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "094G.005", "194G.015"]
>>> [x.lstrip('0') for x in gList]
['94G.016', '94G.019', '94G.005', '194G.015']
```

**improving your approach:**
with every iteration x points to the current item, so apply `lstrip()` on x not on `gList`

**using item:**

```
for x in gList:  
    x.lstrip("0")
```

**using index**:

```
for index in xrange(len(gList)):   #xrange() or(range() in python 3.x) returns a iterable which contains values from 0 to len(gList)-1 
    gList[index].lstrip("0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the beauty of list comprehensions on python docs.

A solution would be

Removing the item:

```
[item for item in gList if item[0] != '0']
```

or removing the leading '0'

```
[item.lstrip('0') for item in gList]
```

Updated answer, since I cannot post comments.

Comment: I was about to post this but I think he actually wants to remove the character, not the whole element (as per Ashwini's answer).

Comment: Now I can post comments? Something's weird. Well he wasnt very precise in his question...

Comment: Your edit just adds @Ashwini's solution to yours.... By the way, I misread the question just like you too :-/

Comment: Yes, I just want to remove all "0" from each item in the list

Comment: @user765015 a *single* leading `0` from each item right? Not all `0` in the item .. just to clarify. (Sample output would have been helpful in the original post)

Comment: @user765015 what's your expected output?

Comment: Very sorry about not being clear, I have made edits to my post based on your comments and will try to ask better more concise questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code:

```
gList = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "094G.005", "194G.015"]

outL=[]
for x in gList:
    outL.append(x.lstrip("0"))

print outL
# prints ['94G.016', '94G.019', '94G.005', '194G.015']
```

As others have said, this is easier with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x.lstrip('0') for x in gList]
['94G.016', '94G.019', '94G.005', '194G.015']
```

Or, better still, a generator:

```
>>> (x.lstrip('0') for x in gList)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c27c140>
>>> list(_)
['94G.016', '94G.019', '94G.005', '194G.015']
```

**Edit**

You can do a generator two ways easily.

First is to write a function:

```
def rem0(data):
    for x in data:
       yield x.lstrip('0')

for i in rem0(gList):
   print i
```

The other is a gen expression right where you need it:

```
for i in (x.lstrip('0') for x in gList): 
   print i
```

Or even:

```
g=(x.lstrip('0') for x in gList)
for i in g:
    ...
```

Both ways print your desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure what the list(_) is doing? How would I write the generator in a function? See my Edit for what I' trying to do.

Comment: @user765015: The `list(_)` shows the contents of the generator expression. Otherwise you get `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c27c140>`